# Front-end development

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, frontend

everyone! I'm only a beginner at making websites, but I have a task of making a website for one volunteer-organization project and the designer asked me if it is possible to make an animation from the background of the first section of [this](https://georgepustovit.dev/) website.

I made a little inverstigation and here is what I have found out: after downoading all the files from the georgepustovit.dev at the sources tab

[here is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUTnl.png)

and putting them in the right hierarchy on my local computer

[here is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBlEy.png)

I can open the website, but still cannot see the animation.

Also, I have found out that during the load of the website (when I load it from my computer) I have mistakes only with the downloaded files

[here is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEAXj.png)

I would be very greateful to you if you can help me with this issue: any comments on what I should read, what I should use, how can I make such animation by myself (having not much knowledge) and other possible ways to solve my problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected the Website & the Animation on that page is not really animation, it's a `canvas`

Here's a [Blog](https://medium.com/@twineworks/fun-with-html-canvas-build-the-matrix-c87c4bb12487) describing how to do it. Obviously, you will need to tweak some animation & duration setting manually in order to get it to work the way you want.